# Android - Create speedometer as image

Tags: android, graph

I have to creating speedometer like image [image: Image Like this]. I followed may tutorials from here [Tutorial 1](https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView) and another [Tutorial 2](https://github.com/bilthon/Android-Speedometer)

But not worked. Please help or suggested some method to achive this.

Thanks in advance.